# How to check the username in text file or not and then ask for the password?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
loginUsername = input("Enter Username: ")
loginPassword = input("Enter PASSWORD: ")

data=open('database.txt', 'r')
accounts = data.readlines()

for line in data:
    accounts = line.split(",")
    if (loginUsername == accounts[0] and loginPassword == accounts[1]):
        print("LOGGED IN")
    else:
        print("Login FAILED")

print(accounts)
```

I want to make a text login system, which will ask for the username first. After checking the text file which stored username and password, the system will ask for password. But I don't know how to read the first column (which is username, the structure of the text file is "username, password"). If i use readlines() and split(","). But there is "n" at the end of the password.

Comment: What is: `accounts = data.readlines()`? Surely this exhausts the file.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20424903/mike). If the answer you received solved your issue, you can mark it as "correct", by clicking on the check mark beside the answer, to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 3):

```
# You should always use CamelCase for class names and snake_case
# for everything else in Python as recommended in PEP8.
username = input("Enter Username: ")
password = input("Enter Password: ")

# You can use a list to store the database's credentials.
credentials = []

# You can use context manager that will automatically
# close the file for you, when you are done with it.
with open("database.txt") as data:
    for line in data:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        credentials.append(line.split(","))

authorized = False

for credential in credentials:
    db_username = credential[0]
    db_password = credential[1]
    if username == db_username and password == db_password:
        authorized = True

if authorized:
    print("Login Succeeded.")
else:
    print("Login Failed.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The "n" at the end of the password is probably the newline character `\n`. In order to remove it, you can use the `rstrip()` function:

```
mystring = "password\n"
print(mystring.rstrip())

>>> 'password'
```